# Can't login to Wekan DB CentOS console

Tags: mongodb

I have recently installed Wekan on a CentOS (CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810) server and it works well. However I need to login to the MongoDB. I have followed the installation guide of MongoDB and set a password for 'admin' user. But when When the "mongo -u admin -p" command is entered it prompts for password and I get the following error. However I have another issue not starting "mongod", but it is enabled.

```
connecting to: test
2020-06-12T01:20:23.618-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2020-06-12T01:20:23.618-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

I created this user in mongo which does not seem to work when trying to login to the DB.

```
$ mongo

db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin",
    pwd: "abcd1234",
    roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Firstly I installed the latest version of mongodb and then I downgraded to to 3.2 which works with wekan.  However Wekan still works fine without any issue.
This is the error I get when starting the mongod.

```
$ systemctl start mongod

Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ systemctl enable mongod

mongod.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig mongod on
```

The port mongod uses is 27019 which I found from the following command.

```
$ ss -nutlp
tcp    LISTEN     0      128        127.0.0.1:27019      *:*       users:(("mongod",pid=11578,fd=6))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

In the output of the mongo shell connection failure:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: errno:111 Connection refused
```

This tells you that it is attempting to connect to port 27017 on localhost, and that the operating system actively refused the connection because nothing is listening on that port.

The ss output shows that mongod is listening on port 27019.

Try adding `--port 27019` to your mongo command line.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But I created the user admin but cannot login to 27019 instance still.